# Mongoose, how to empty a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've the following hapi.js server

```
const Hapi = require('hapi')
const Mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Wreck = require('wreck');


const server = new Hapi.Server({
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3000
})

Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB', { useNewUrlParser: true })

const BlockModel = Mongoose.model('block', {
    height: Number,
    size: Number,
    time: Number
})

server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/",
    handler: async (request, h) => {

        Mongoose.model.blocks.remove({});    //<------This is the part of the code I intend to use to delete the collection

        const { res, payload } = await Wreck.get('https://api.url');
        let myJson = JSON.parse(payload.toString()).blocks
        console.log(myJson)
        for (let i = 0; i<myJson.length; i++) {
            var block = new BlockModel({  height: myJson[i].height, size: myJson[i].size, time: myJson[i].time });
            block.save();
        }
        console.log(myJson)

        return "test"
    }
})



server.start();
```

Point is, it works fine and saves the desired data to my collection, but ofc the database will keep growing if I dont delete the data on each execution. So I intend to implement something similar to

```
db.blocks.remove({}) //where blocks is my collection
```

Which works fine in the mongoconsole.
But I cant find how to implement this in the code

Comment: try `BlockModel.remove({}, callback)`

Comment: @kalimba althought it doesnt crash now, it doesnt seem to be removing anything on each execution, since the db keeps growing and i have to empty it manually

Comment: @kalimbda the remove operator does not exist in mongoose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the deleteMany operator with an empty filter.

```
db.collection.deleteMany({})
```

or with your model:

```
await BlockModel.deleteMany({})
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty all collections in a db

```
const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({})
}
```

Comment: Alternative: `await Promise.all(Object.values( mongoose.connection.collections ).map( async (collection) => { await collection.deleteMany({}); }) );`