# How to delete all documents of all collections in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using the Mongoose ODM with a MongoDB instance, how can one delete all documents in all collections of the database instance, without necessarily destroying the collections themselves or their indexes?

For contrast:

```js
await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();
```

> Deletes the given database, including all collections, documents, and indexes.

according to the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-dropDatabase), which is not desired.

Comment: See also this answer on a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64260910/12109043

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over all collections in the database given by the values of the [`Connection.prototype.collections`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-collections) hash, and use [`Query.prototype.deleteMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-deleteMany) to delete every document in the collection.

The `deleteMany()` query/operation is asynchronous (it returns a [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) promise-like object). In order to iteratively perform the operations for all collections, we can map each collection to a promise with an asynchronous callback in which we `await` the call, and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve when all of the queries have resolved.

```js
async function clearCollections() {
  const collections = mongoose.connection.collections;

  await Promise.all(Object.values(collections).map((collection) =>
    collection.deleteMany({}) // an empty mongodb selector object ({}) must be passed as the filter argument
  ));
}
```

Comment: One note is that this is not necessarily atomic, and may not be suited for concurrent environments where such operations are expected to be transactional.

Comment: When you're using `Promise.all()` there is no need to async await in the loop. `await Promise.all(Object.values(mongoose.connection.collections).map(col => col.deleteMany({})))` will do.